# How to change TableRow height in Android?

Tags: java, android, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I want to customize TableRow in my app - change it's height in order i can place two rows of buttons in it. I can't implement it in UI designer. So the question - how can I do this programmaticaly in XML or Java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are wanting, but here is how you can get "rows" of `Buttons` in one `TableRow`. Do something similar to this and see if that is what you are talking about.

I added a `LinearLayout` to the `TableRow` that is `vertical orientation` and then wrapper the `Buttons` in another `LinearLayout` that is `horizontal orientation`.

```
<TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ABCDE" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ABC" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ABCDE" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ABC" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```